# Lauch a call Intent from a fragment and get back to it

Tags: java, android, android-intent, fragment, call

Am having a hard time launching a dial phone intent and then coming back to the app when the back button is pressed, the call function below works perfectly in normal activity but closes the app when called from within a fragment.

```
    call.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (driverFoundID != null) {
                    String id = driverFoundID;
                    final DatabaseReference getDrivesrnameAndMobile = 

FirebaseDatabase. getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child("Drivers").child(id);
                    getDrivesrnameAndMobile.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            if (dataSnapshot.child("name").exists() && dataSnapshot.child("mobile").exists()) {
                                String name = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
                                String mobile = dataSnapshot.child("mobile").getValue().toString();
                                dialContactPhone(mobile);
                            } else {
                                snackbarShow("Driver credentials missing");
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                            snackbarShow(databaseError.getMessage().toString());
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    snackbarShow("Driver credentials missing");
                }
            }
        });

//Funtion
private void dialContactPhone(final String phoneNumber) {
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.fromParts("tel", 
phoneNumber, null)));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

For a fragment,

```
private void dialContactPhone(final String phoneNumber) {

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phoneNumber));
getActivity().startActivity(intent);

}
```

Comment: It still doesn't work @Sanjay, i've updated my question to show the context from where am calling the function.

Comment: i guess something else is wrong.this is the code to open dial pad.please find where the problem is and then edit the question again.As far as I know ,the problem is not with the intent code